# Workbook protection causing "External table is not in the expected format" in SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis

I have an SSIS package that is supposed to load files from excel into SQL Server.

Process goes smoothly when excel workbook is not password protected. But when I password protects this workbook, I starts getting error **External table is not in the expected format**. Any solution that can be done within SSIS to enable SSIS to read this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The almighty internet search engines suggest it cannot be done:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139836.aspx

> Note
>
> You cannot connect to a password-protected Excel file.

However you could create a little tool in another language (powershell is suggested) that will be able to open the excels for you with the passwords (that you have to provide this tool) and save a version of the workbook without password for your SSIS to use.

Alternatively: Dont password protect the excels you use for your SSIS. For protection you might consider setting up a location with limited/restricted/no access for all users but the one that will run the SSIS.