# How to configure an OLE DB connection manager that connects to an excel file

Tags: ssis, oledb

I want to to configure a connection to an Excel 2007 (.xlsx) File.

I want to use an OLE DB connection manager, and for Provider, i have select Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider. Then, on the All page of the Connection Manager dialog box, for Extended Properties, i have entered Excel 12.0.

For server of file name, i have entered the full path to my excel file. I am however having trouble configuring the **Log on to the server options**. Which user Name and password are they asking for here?, the excel file is not password protected. see Screenshot below

[image]

And when i click Test Connection, i get error below

[image]

Comment: did you try adding ;IMEX=1 to the Extended properties along with the Excel 12.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open and close the excel file manually saving.

additionally

I Think you should use a `Excel source` ,instead of `ole db source` and configure as shown here in links

<kbd>[link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181175.aspx)</kbd>

<kbd>[link2](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2770/importing-data-from-excel-using-ssis--part-1/)</kbd>

<kbd>[check this out which is your case](http://bensullins.com/using-excel-2007-files-as-a-source-in-ssis-2005/)</kbd>

<kbd>[see this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492137/workbook-protection-causing-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format-in-ss)</kbd>

Comment: With the excel source, i am coming across the the issues mentioned in this post http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/mssqlserver/what-s-the-deal-with/ and the server admins will never edit the TypeGuessRows registry setting in the registry and i completely have no control over the excel file

Answer (score -1):

You can input 'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES' into 'Extended Properties', then save, because the connection you chose is the default for Access.